# Java fx Getter and Setter Methods For radio button color changes

Tags: javafx

For the life of me i cant get this to work, at the end of my code here you can see that i am trying to make a getting and setter method so that i can change the body color of my cars using radio buttons. The code is bellow!

```
package racecar;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLUE;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class RaceCar extends Application {

public class CarPane extends Pane {

    public final double radius = 20;
    private double x = radius, y = radius;
    private double dx = 1;
    private Circle circle = new Circle(x + 10, y, radius);
    private Circle circle2 = new Circle(x + 60, y, radius);
    private Rectangle body = new Rectangle(x - 20, y - 45, 120, 25);
    private Polygon roof = new Polygon(
            x, y - 45,
            x + 70, y - 45,
            x + 50, y - 90,
            x + 10, y - 90
    );
    private Timeline animation;

    public CarPane() {
        circle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        circle2.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        body.setFill(Color.RED);
        roof.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        getChildren().addAll(circle, circle2, body, roof);

        animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), e -> moveCar()));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();
    }

    public void play() {
        animation.play();
    }

    public void pause() {
        animation.pause();
    }

    public void iSpeed() {
        animation.setRate(animation.getRate() + 2);
    }

    public void dSpeed() {
        animation.setRate(
                animation.getRate() > 0 ? animation.getRate() - 2 : 0);
    }

    protected void moveCar() {
        if (x < getWidth()) {
            dx *= 1;
        } else {
            x = 0;
        }

        x += dx;
        body.setX(x - 25);
        roof.setLayoutX(x - 25);
        circle.setCenterX(x);
        circle2.setCenterX(x + 60);
    }

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    CarPane cpane = new CarPane();
    BorderPane bpane = new BorderPane();
    HBox hbox = new HBox(8);

    HBox ipane = new HBox(cpane);
    ipane.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    bpane.setBottom(ipane);

    Button btStart = new Button("Start");
    btStart.setOnAction(e
            -> {
        cpane.play();
    });

    Button btStop = new Button("Stop");
    btStop.setOnAction(e
            -> {
        cpane.pause();
    });

    VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
    RadioButton rbBlue = new RadioButton("Blue");
    RadioButton rbGreen = new RadioButton("Green");
    RadioButton rbRed = new RadioButton("Red");
    RadioButton rbYellow = new RadioButton("Yellow");

    ToggleGroup tgroup = new ToggleGroup();
    rbBlue.setToggleGroup(tgroup);
    rbGreen.setToggleGroup(tgroup);
    rbRed.setToggleGroup(tgroup);
    rbYellow.setToggleGroup(tgroup);

    rbRed.setSelected(true);

    cpane.setOnMouseClicked(e
            -> {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            cpane.iSpeed();
        } else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            cpane.dSpeed();
        }
    });
    hbox.getChildren().addAll(btStart, btStop);
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(rbBlue, rbGreen, rbRed, rbYellow);
    bpane.setLeft(vbox);
    bpane.setTop(hbox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(bpane, 600, 600);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Racing Car");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    cpane.requestFocus();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
public void setBodyColor(Color c) {
    this.bodyColor = c;
    CarPane();
}

public void getBodyColor() {
    return bodyColor;
}

}
```

I am then after getting the getter and setter methods to work will do this to make it change colors.

```
rbBlue.setOnAction(e ->{
   if(rbBlue.isSelected()) 
   {
       CarPane.setBodyColor(RED);
   }
    });
```

Anyone know how i can get them setter and getters to work?

Comment: The code you shared is wither incomplete or wrong. `CarPane` has no method `setBodyColor`, so I can't see how the line `CarPane.setBodyColor(RED)` compiles. Additionally, `bodyColor` is never defined. The statement `CarPane();` also seems erroneous to me, as it looks like an object creation, but there is no `new` keyword.

Comment: Thank you lol, my brain must ave not been working.